# Damaged Expired Work Visa

Tags: visas

I need to get re-stamp on my visa via drop box. The machine readable zone in my expired visa is little damaged. Characters are peeling off. Thought that is readable enough but will it be a problem?
I am attaching a photo for reference. Should I completely peel it off or use glue.

Comment: Note: your photo may contain private information, so I recommend you to remove the photo. Next time you edit a photo: do not use "transparency inks": the black part is still visible, and you should remove all part of the characters. With your photo, it is not difficult to find what is "hidden".

Answer (score 6):

If the damaged visa is expired, then I can't imagine it would matter at all. The machine readable zone repeats the important parts of your information that is available visually on the rest of the visa. If somebody were to try to read that visa with a machine reader, and it didn't work, then they would manually enter the information from the visa page. This is considered a normal wear and tear.

**Do not attempt to repair or alter your passport** yourself. That's a good way to invalidate the whole passport. Even if its just a visa page, immigration officials will suspect that you are trying to hide something and will not allow you to proceed.